# Equation environment

Tags: equations, multline

I use texmaker program.
I can not jump up to next line by using symbol `\\` in equation environment:

```
\begin{equation}....\end{equation}
```

I could do it before but now I can't. In other environments, I can do it.
Could you show me how to solve this problem, please?

Comment: You can't do it in the equation environment. Use one of the amsmath's environment: `align`, `gather`, `multine` and the like.

Comment: Yes, I am using align environment. But I want to know why I cann't do it in equation evr.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Because `equation` is not designed to do it!

Comment: Just to elaborate on @HarishKumars comment. `equation` and `align` are made in significantly different ways. And thus does not share the same features. For example, `equation` can alter the spacing above the env under certain conditions. Because of the may `align` works, it cannot. Therefore it is generally recommended *not to use* `align` for one-line equations.

Comment: @daleif: is it the same for `gather`?

Comment: As far as I know yes. It is only `equation` that has the the *grow from the middle* plus *look at the last line of the preceding paragraph* feature. It is possible to patch `align` to be able to do something similar. But I do not know if that patch breaks anything else (I did not write the patch, someone else submitted it for `mathtools` but I've been reluctant to include it).

Comment: @Bernard -- all of the `amsmath` multi-line structures are built in essentially the same way.  `equation` is different because it is defined essentially the same as in basic latex; only a `*` form has been added.

Comment: Unfortunately, MathJax allows ``\\`` in `equation`, which can be grossly misleading to its users when they switch to proper LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You have *never* been able to use `\\` in the `equation` environment. The usage of it in that environment has *always* produced errors, because `equation` can just contain one line. An exception is the usage of internal auxiliary environments such as `split`, `aligned` or `alignedat`, but in this case `\\` would not be in the `equation` environment, but in the auxiliary one.

Load `amsmath` with `\usepackage{amsmath}` in any document that has math.

If you want to display two consecutive equations as if each is in `equation`, then use `gather`:

```
\begin{gather}
\cosh^{2} t - \sinh^{2} t = 1 \\
2\sinh^{2} t + 1 = \sinh 2t
\end{gather}
```

If you want to highlight the equals signs, use `align`:

```
\begin{align}
2\sinh t &= e^{t}-e^{-t} \\
2\cosh t &= e^{t}+e^{-t}
\end{align}
```

---

Note: MathJax allows using `\\` in `equation` or `\[...\]`. I think this is a bad mistake, because it makes for unportable code.